# kafka-python basic producing and consuming not working

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, kafka-python

I am new to kafka and I'm trying to run basic example.

My kafka is running with this config: https://developer.confluent.io/quickstart/kafka-docker/

python 3.7; kafka installation as follows: `pip install kafka-python`
(2.0.2)

I follow this doc; then I run two consoles (one for each of consume and produce)

consumer:

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
for m in KafkaConsumer('my-topic', bootstrap_servers='broker'):
    print(m)
```

producer:

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
p = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='broker')
p.send('my-topic', b'my message!')
```

And after `p.send()` I expect to that consumer gets the message. But nothing happens.
What is wrong with my setup?

**Edit:** consoles are run container within the same docker-compose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`broker` only resolves inside the docker-compose network, if you are running the scripts in the host, you should use `localhost`.

And if you are running the scripts as containers in the same docker-compose, you should use `broker:29092` since there is where Kafka is listening for connections from within the docker-compose network.

Comment: I was sure that `bootstrap_servers='broker'` is correct, bc if I put there deliberately incorrect value, like `browker`, the error happens upon object creation. But adding port like this `bootstrap_servers='broker:29092'` solved the problem.